# How to determine amplitude of compton scattering using Feynman rules?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I am currently studying from Griffiths' introduction to elementary particles.
I started reading about the Feynman  rules for caclulating scattering amplitudes, and while I understood them for the cases of electron/muon scattering, I can't understand how to proceed in the case of Compton Scattering.
Particularly, considering the following case:

[image]

I know that I should consider going from the "end" of the trajectory back in time. But the fact that the electron has a weird trajectory, I don't know if that is the way to go here. Should I consider $\bar{u}(p_4)$, then the vertex $ig_e\gamma^\mu$, then the propagator $\frac{i(\gamma^\mu q_\mu + mc)}{q^2-m^2c^2}$ then another vertex and then the incoming electron $u(p_1)$? But what do I do with the photons then, since the trajectory is interrupted?
I would really appreciate an explanation as to how to approach these diagrams

Comment: Fortunately it doesn't matter for the photons as those are given by polarization vectors and don't contain spinor indices, and hence can be placed anywhere in that expression. The best thing is to just follow the fermion line and attach two photons to the resulting expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incoming photon will contribute with a $\epsilon_\mu(p_2)$, and the outgoing one with a $\epsilon_\nu(p_3)^*$. Note that the $\mu$ index of the incoming photon will be contracted with the one of $\gamma^\mu$, and the $\nu$ index of the outgoing photon will be contracted with the index of the other vertex. You can place them wherever you want, since they are just numbers ($\epsilon_\mu$ is the $\mu$-th component of the polarization vector).

By the way, I recommend you use another index in the propagator, since $\mu$ is already in use.

Comment: but the photon has two independent polarization vectors, then how $\epsilon_\mu$ can be just a number?

Comment: The two independent polarization vectors can be given by $\epsilon^{(1)}=(0,1,0,0)$ and $\epsilon^{(2)}=(0,0,1,0)$ in the Coulomb gauge. $\epsilon^{(s)}_\mu$ is the $\mu$-th component of the $s$-polarization vector.

Comment: ok I got it. Thanks